# Python inserting html into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to insert HTML code into a field in a MySQL db.

I use the following code to do it

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `table1`(field1) VALUES("+ str(data) +")")
```

But I get the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near \'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or\' at line 3')
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) what does `data` look like,  b) please please please don't use string concatenation to create SQL queries, use prepared statements or an ORM

Comment: Obligatory XKCD link: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo - I see it as less clear cut. Either you sanitise your SQL or you never ever let anyone ever use your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape your string:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `table1`(field1) VALUES('"+ conn.escape_string(str(data))+"')")
```

Where `conn` is your connection.

Comment: I tried the following, however I got the error that conn. is not defined,so I changed it to mysqldb and it said that: `code`_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\\r\\n\\r\\n<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\\" \\"http:\' at line 1')
`code`

Comment: Can you post generated query? Also try to use this kind of brackets: `'`

Comment: The code works! Thanks! But I can seem to only select data, but it's not inserting. When I start a new .py file and use the same code to insert and it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Used: con.commit(). Works perfect now! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check your string - it looks like you are escaping single quotes but leaving double quotes un-escaped (and since you're enclosing with double-quotes, the string closes 'early').